# telebot Как отправить сообщение о запуске бота

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Мне нужно сделать уведомление о запуске бота, я не понимаю как это сделать. Вот мой код:

```
 @bot.message_handler()
 def run_message(message):
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Бот запущен!")
```

Comment: Уведомление кому?

Comment: Вы молодец, но что с кодом то не так?

Comment: Уведомление всем кто писал start, код не работает

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start])
 def run_message(message):
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Бот запущен!")
```

Comment: *@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
 def run_message(message):
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Бот запущен!")

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]